# In a rails update action, new column gets updated only on second try

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a posts table in my rails app, with title and body fields.

I create a few posts from the browser, adding titles and bodies.

Now I add an author column to the post table:

```
> rails g migration AddAuthorToPosts author:string
```

And modify the form to add the author field:

```
<%= f.label :author %>
<%= f.text_field :author %>
```

And add the attribute to strong_params in controller:

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :author)
end
```

When I now edit existing posts, I find that the author field does show up in the form, but it does not get saved the first time. When I repeat editing the same post, and change the author field again, it does get saved

The update method in the controller, which is where the problem lies, is:

```
@post = Post.find(params[:id])

if @post.update(post_params)
  flash[:notice] = "Success!" 
  redirect_to @post
  return
else
  render 'edit'
end
```

I want the existing posts to get edited the first time I update them.

I realize I need to do something else instead of @post.update(post_params) in the controller update action, but not sure what.

Comment: can you add a snippet of the rails server logs when you submit the form? Thanks. The @post.update(post_params) I think is correct.

Comment: @JeffreyMCastro - It didn't happen on local - I restarted the production (heroku) server after running the migration, and the problem doesn't happen any more.